# using output of one query in another in kql

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

```
let average = materialize(FooTable
| summarize avg(value) by group, class
| summarize arg_min(avg_value, class) by group
```

This should output something like (i.e. minimum value for the group averages per class):

| group | class | avg_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | C1 | 100 |
| G2 | C2 | 150 |
| .. | .. | .. |

Now, I would like to display all the group, class and value row which shows the delta from their group's minimum class average as calculated by the query above.

```
FooTable
| where value > ( here I want to insert the query to get min by group and class)
```

Output should be something like:

| group | class | min_avg_value | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | C1 | 100 | 0 |
| G1 | C2 | 120 | 20 |
| G2 | C1 | 200 | 50 |
| G2 | C2 | 150 | 0 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/lookupoperator)

```
let FooTable = datatable (group:string, class:string, value:int)
[
    'G1' ,'C1', 100
   ,'G1' ,'C2', 120
   ,'G2' ,'C1', 200
   ,'G2' ,'C2', 150
];
let average = materialize(
FooTable
| summarize avg(value) by group, class
| summarize min(avg_value) by group
);
FooTable
| lookup kind=inner average on group
| extend delta = value - min_avg_value
```

| Show expand view | group | class | value | min_avg_value | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | C1 | 100 | 100 | 0 |  |
| G1 | C2 | 120 | 100 | 20 |  |
| G2 | C1 | 200 | 150 | 50 |  |
| G2 | C2 | 150 | 150 | 0 |  |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12PwQqDMAyG74W+Q24qOFBhF8XTYHuB3cYY2QxSrK3UKtvw4VfLLGztpfn4m3yRZOGo9RnvkqCGBq276ztujZ6GcrRGqDaFh8RxDNWMcqJSKJtwduEM3IlOeQRpdMijFPIs8zDdYLHCIsAiJIvsD/rk3sFrxZl0cjiTwXZ169GSESjFm2LONmnOFhinvkfjuEu3sZdL4P4Cv8LX/TfXCxW77O0vy1lS/baWWnfTAJ1QTS2UIhOEtNr+LEBPS6qBhqRFZ+q7wm6dcgtTPnRfInhqAQAA)

Answer (score 1):

[join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

```
let FooTable = datatable (group:string, class:string, value:int)
[
    'G1' ,'C1', 100
   ,'G1' ,'C2', 120
   ,'G2' ,'C1', 200
   ,'G2' ,'C2', 150
];
let average = materialize(
FooTable
| summarize avg(value) by group, class
| summarize min(avg_value) by group
);
average
| join kind=inner FooTable on group
| extend delta = value - min_avg_value
```

| group | min_avg_value | group1 | class | value | delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | 100 | G1 | C1 | 100 | 0 |
| G1 | 100 | G1 | C2 | 120 | 20 |
| G2 | 150 | G2 | C1 | 200 | 50 |
| G2 | 150 | G2 | C2 | 150 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA12QwYrCMBCG74G8w9zaQoW24MXFk6Av4E0WGe1QsptOJE3L7uLDOwm2siaX5ONL/j%20xFGDv3BEvlmALLQaZcZ133o23zRC84a6Eq8VhWHYT2pE2hkOh1UkrkJEd6gzKbFdnJdRVlWA5wybCZoHNYjbVG0zmWuDnh1ZWyuFEHrvYrcdA3qA1f5RrNZfW6g7D2PfohYvd5alcAZdfSE94dv/v9YZzcc9vrlaFxD4j44kvZxi%20Dbdbw0z%209VWO5xN3oJ9A3EJLNqD0THfCKmacl4wHrErt1WgBAAA=)