# KQL Query for Azure Sentinel

Tags: azure, kql, azure-sentinel

Need assistance in getting the summary of user domains from sentinel signinglogs.

```
SigninLogs
| where AppId == "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
| extend UserDomains = split(UserPrincipalName,'@')[1]
| summarize  TotalAttempts = count(), Failed=countif(ResultType !=0), Succeded=countif(ResultType ==0), LastAttempt = max(TimeGenerated), FirstAttempt = min(TimeGenerated), CountofUniqueID = dcount(UserPrincipalName), DomainCount = dcount(tostring(UserDomains))
```

The result has most of the information I need. However, I need little bit more clarity.
The objective of this report is to understand how may external users are consuming this applications and from which all domains they are accessing. So I need to make a summary based on internal users and external users.

[image: Need something like this]

How can I get the the count of all signed in users who are having a domain name ending with *mydomain.com (covering the root domain and child domains)

How can I get the the count of user domains specific to external users, ie the unique user domains - internal user domains (anything ending with *mydomain.com)
Is there a way to concatenate all the external domains with ";" as a delimiter ? In PowerShell, we use -join ";". Anything similar for KQL?

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: This post is not compliant with SO guidelines. The easiest way to fix it would be to add a sample data + required results in textual format (CSV/TSV/JSON etc.) and remove the multiple questions at the end of the post. P.S. just put the data As Is, even if looks messy.

Comment: Thanks, I have adjusted the post as per your suggestion.

Comment: You did make some adjustments, but you didn't follow the guidelines.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not sure if I can make it further more simple. So I have decided to split into multiple questions. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Buddy, you are asking to assist you writing a query, based on a data I don't have access to.  All you need to do is supply a data sample + required results. See this question as example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73563960/using-output-of-one-query-in-another-in-kql/73564561#73564561. As I said before - you don't need to format it nicely, just put it As Is in CSV/TSV/JSON format. Please make sure that you are not putting any sensitive data here.